# D-link router URL blocking

Tags: router, web-filtering

I want to be able to block all sites except the sites on a whitelist. The D-link router does this just fine, but the list can only contain up to 40 urls. Is there a way I can allow more sites?

Answer (score 1):

[Sophos UTM](http://www.sophos.com/en-us/products/free-tools/sophos-utm-home-edition.aspx) can do that & more, filter by site, by country, by subject matter; with exceptions on a grep

Freeware, bring your own computer & 2 NICs.

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

Comment: That seems like it would be an awesome solution, but it looks like by the requirements that I would need a dedicated computer, something which i don't have and might be more expensive to get one than a normal router.

Comment: Yes, it does need an entire 'puter dedicated to the task - but in fact, as a router/gateway, it really doesn't need to be all that fabulous... you're not gaming on it, just passing data. Mine is just an old Core duo machine I picked up for a tenner [complete] & just added a second NIC, another tenner. 2GB RAM, 500GB HD, built-in graphics [as it runs headless], just old stuff I had kicking around. Works perfectly & cheaper than buying a new hardware router.

Comment: AND it's corporate-grade, just without a licence for some of the [very much] higher functions.